# Log4net rollingfile appender skipping every other day in asp.net mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net

I've set up some log4net logging on an asp.net mvc application i've had running for a little over a month now.
I've set up rolling file (and smtp) appender on it.

The application is hit several thousand times a day - alot of actions are logged. On top of these a number of batch jobs are run as part of the application that also write to the log.

Now - as i've been occupied with other work, i've not attended to this application much assuming things to be working based on my test setup.

Unfortunately i discover that the rolling file appender on my production server seems to be skipping every other day.
Ie i have logs :
10/4/2010, 
10/4/2010.1,
10/4/2010.2, 
12/4/2010, 
12/4/2010.1 , 
14/4/2010,
14/4/2010.1

etc.

Any idea what could be causing this? It is absolutely impossible that there has no action on these odd days for the lifetime of the application.

Cheers

Comment: Have you confirmed that there was actually an activity on your site on these days, looking at the IIS logs?

Answer (score 0):

If your batch jobs are writing to the same files as the asp.net mvc app, then it might be a locking issue. Make sure that you have the minimal lock setting in all of your config files.